# Windows Vista Installation constantly fails

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, windows-vista

I wanted to downgrade from Windows 7 to Windows Vista. I backed up all my files to another partition, and then I proceeded to install the update. The first time I tried, I received this error `"Can not install required files, file may be corrupt or missing"`

Then, I reburned the ISO file to another CD, this time at a slower write speed to ensure that the files burned properly. Then, I booted into the CD, put in my product key, and the installation began.
It looked like it was running fine, better than the first time. So I left it to go do my own thing and I came back to and error message telling me:

```
Windows could not set the offline locale information.
```

I proceeded to get very angry and shout several profanities. I tried to boot back into Windows 7, but since the installation had already started and moved some of the files. It won't boot.

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the things I would try in your situation, listed in the order I'd attempt each:

1. **Try another DVD drive.**  Yours may not be reliably reading the data on your installation disc.
2. **Try another installation disc.** This issue has bad media written all over it.
3. **Try another installation disc, burned from yet another DVD burner.**  Yes, this issue has bad media...
4. **Run HDD diagnostics.** I use the free [Ultimate Boot CD](https://www.ultimatebootcd.com) which includes diagnostic tools from every major disk manufacturer.
5. **Delete any existing partitions before starting the Windows install.** This can be done at the beginning of the Windows installation in the Advanced options.  If possible, delete *all* partitions from the disk (but be sure there's nothing you need on them before you do so).  It's possible existing files on the disk are goofing up the installer.
6. **Clean your computer while you're going to all this trouble.**  I guess that won't get Vista installed though.
7. **Try the installation with only essential devices connected to the computer.**  If you have a second hard drive, disconnect it. If you have multiple DVD drives, only have one connected. If you have an add-on video card and video integrated into the motherboard, remove the add-on card and perform the install using the built-in card.
8. **Try reseating your RAM.**
9. **Install the latest BIOS update.**
10. **Try another installation disc.**  Did I mention this sounds like bad media?

Comment: I think my hard drive has a bad sector. I think it may be a soft bad sector, not a hard one. I'm gonna try using a USB as my bootable device, then fix the bad sectors from there before installing. My system wasn't having any problems before I attempted to install Vista, except for the fact that my Windows 7 had been invalidated after I resized my Ubuntu partition. I believe that is what created the bad sectors.

Comment: I've run memtest for 5 hours and I have no errors so far, but I have 4  GB of Memory, so it could take a while.

Comment: I don't think the issue is your memory. Soft/logical disk errors should not be at fault because you should be installing to a newly created partition which will therefore have no logical structure prior to beginning the install. That reminded me that you should also run HDD diagnostics and I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Could I use chkdsk? Because if the HDD diagnostic program isn't for Ubuntu, I can't use it, since I no longer have a Windows operating system.

Comment: You boot from the Ultimate Boot CD so it needs no installed operating system whatsoever to run. The HDD diagnostics will be superior to running `CHKDSK` in this case.

Comment: Great! I'll try it out.

Comment: I used the Diagnosis tool, and it did not pass one of the tests. What do I do now?

Comment: You need to replace your HDD. If it's still under warranty, there may have been a failure code provided by the diagnostic that you'll need to provide when making your warranty claim.

Comment: It turns out your initial statement was right. It was bad media. I went out and bought me a 16 GB Flash Drive and made it bootable and installed it from there, and it worked like a charm. :)

Comment: Glad to have been able to point you in the correct direction. Don't forget to mark this as the answer for the benefit of future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Check ram. Download and use memtest:
http://www.memtest86.com

There is a similar tool on windows 7 cd (maybe on vista too) but i prefer memtest for this job.

Comment: I have downloaded Ubuntu and I'm dual booting, and I think GRUB comes with memtest. And, If the RAM Returns an error, what should I do?

Comment: You should replace the dimm. If you have at least two dimms on your system, try them alternatively with memtest to identify the defective one.

Comment: I'm running memtest right now. It isn't finished, I'll let you know what happens afterward.

Comment: @TheMetaphorer Were you having trouble with your system before attempting to install Windows Vista?  If so, bad RAM could definitely be your culprit as a machine with memory errors will crash randomly and otherwise behave poorly.  However, if you weren't experiencing such issues, your RAM isn't likely at fault.

Comment: I believe the problem is with a bad sector, because I did 6 passes on Memtest over a period of 6 and a half hours, and I received no errors whatsoever.

Comment: Well it' enough to discard ram issue. Now, to try the disk and to check for defective sectors, you should boot the installation cd in repair mode and with a command prompt (found in manual recovery options) you can test the volume with "chkdsk /b". It will test for defective sectors and mark as unusable.